# Self-joining query to find descendants of a node syntax issue

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a self-linking table that records one record for every "Step" in a process (Step.ParentStepId is a foreign key to Step.StepId):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Step](
    [StepId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [text] NULL,
    [Sequence] [int] NULL,
    [ParentStepId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Step] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StepId] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Step]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Step_Step] FOREIGN KEY([ParentStepId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Step] ([StepId])
```

I'd like to write a query to return all of the Steps where a given StepId is a parent (at any level).

Oracle used to have some cool SQL extensions for this. How would this be done in T-SQL, SQL 2008, R2?

Here's my attempt. Help me, please, recursion too often hurts my head.

```
DECLARE @StepId INT = 3

WITH cteRecursion
     AS (SELECT
             Stepid
             ,1 AS Level
         FROM
             Step
         WHERE
             StepId = @StepId
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
             t.StepId
             ,c.Level + 1
         FROM
             Step t
             INNER JOIN cteRecursion c
                 ON t.ParentStepId = c.StepId
        )
SELECT
    StepId,Level
FROM
    cteRecursion
ORDER BY
    Level,
    StepId;
```

when run:

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
>   common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
>   context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Read the fabulous error message!**

It clearly says:

*Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. **If this statement is a common table expression**, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, **the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon**.*

So: terminate your previous statement with a semicolon, and you should be fine!

```
DECLARE @StepId INT = 3

; WITH cteRecursion
     AS (SELECT
             Stepid, 1 AS Level
         FROM
             Step
         WHERE
             StepId = @StepId
        .......
```

Comment: Ah. I guess i was intimidated with the SQL and baled quickly. I never made it past the "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'." STRANGE SYNTAX!! thanks. Is there a way in T-SQL to display the ourput in indented text "tree" format as there is in oracle? This sounds like another SO question for which the answer is probably "no".

Comment: @chad: no, SQL Server will *give* you the data - to prepare / present it, is another job (and not SQL Server's, really)

Comment: I agree. I was surprised that oracle had such a function for formatting tree output. Yet...it was handy for a quick debugging result!

Comment: A follow up question, please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679467/change-a-cte-select-to-a-table-value-user-defined-function

Answer (score 0):

You need a ; before the WITH or else you get this error.