# Change a CTE SELECT to a table value user defined function

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

In an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679065/self-joining-query-to-find-descendants-of-a-node-syntax-issue), I constructed a SQL that uses a CTE with the help from a SO contributor. I'd like now to encapsulate that SQL in a user defined function that returns a table but I am getting the error below.

Here's the code:

```
Alter FUNCTION GetDescendentSteps 
(   
@StepId INT 
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
    ;WITH cteRecursion
         AS (SELECT
                 StepId
                 ,1 AS Level
             FROM
                 Step
             WHERE
                 StepId = @StepId
             UNION ALL
             SELECT
                 t.StepId
                 ,c.Level + 1
             FROM
                 Step t
                 INNER JOIN cteRecursion c
                     ON t.ParentStepId = c.StepId
            )
    SELECT
        StepId,Level
    FROM
        cteRecursion
    ORDER BY
        Level,
        StepId;
```

I get the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetDescendentSteps, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

Note that line 8 is:

```
;WITH cteRecursion
```

..and that if I execute only the SQL beginning at line 8 (after I replace the variable @StepId with a literal).

Also, this simple example works:

```
ALTER FUNCTION GetDescendentSteps 
(   
@StepId INT 
)

RETURNS TABLE 

AS
RETURN
select 7 As Stepid,1 As Level
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the first `;` and the `order by` clause.

```
Alter FUNCTION GetDescendentSteps 
(   
@StepId INT 
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
    WITH cteRecursion
         AS (SELECT
                 StepId
                 ,1 AS Level
             FROM
                 Step
             WHERE
                 StepId = @StepId
             UNION ALL
             SELECT
                 t.StepId
                 ,c.Level + 1
             FROM
                 Step t
                 INNER JOIN cteRecursion c
                     ON t.ParentStepId = c.StepId
            )
    SELECT
        StepId,Level
    FROM
        cteRecursion
```